# Create custom audience on Facebook fails because of invalid Ad Id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create custom audiences from my app and sync the people from my CRM into these audiences.

I am using Facebook's example code for this:

```
//create custom audience in Facebook
            $api = Api::init($fbApp->getAppId(), $fbApp->getAppSecret(), $fbApp->getAccessToken());
            $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

            $fields = [];
            $params = [
                'name' => $audience->getName(),
                'subType' => $audience->getSubtype(),
                'description' => $audience->getDescription(),
                'customer_file_source' => $audience->getCustomerFileSource()
            ];

            $results = json_encode((new AdAccount('act_<adAccountId>'))->createCustomAudience(
                $fields,
                $params
            )->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I replaced  with a valid ad id which I used to run some ads on. I got the response from Facebook:

> Unsupported post request. Object with ID '' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

The raw response from Facebook:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 06:09:42 GMT

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-app-usage: {"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_adAccountId' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
facebook-api-version: v4.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
Pragma: no-cache
x-fb-rev: 1001110245
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store
x-fb-trace-id: A4a2j9KJX6B
x-fb-request-id: AkKQTy7efluqyD0BNHKRVlu
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-FB-Debug: 2ts8Felvz3XZ4tO/rC1uifQwsG/HFhnn9TPUhutY1T03RDFoduHEvdna1MTLzaJuXHo6qk655gP/d2T4fDuf0g==
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 06:09:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 377

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_2520034514937291' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"AkKQTy7efluqyD0BNHKRVlu"}}

I made sure the Facebook ad id is associated with my app. Then, when this failed, I upgraded my app to Business Account and created a new ad id. I got the same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure that you do not use an empty ID anywhere?

Comment: the id is not empty. I used Xdebug to go as deep as possible on Facebook SDK for PHP. I saw it makes a GET request and the ad id I provided is used as $this->data['id']. I am using "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^4.0". I am not sure if I need to give it other permissions..

Comment: What type of access token are you using? What permissions does it contain?

Comment: I am getting the access token like this: $token = $this->curl->get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
   [
    'query' => [
     'client_id'     => $appId,
     'client_secret' => $appSecret,
     'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials'
    ]
   ] );

Comment: `Object with ID 'act_adAccountId' does not exist,` - have you tried checking further what happens?

Comment: Nico, I used xdebug to see exactly what the fb sdk does. What else do you recommend?